# How to draw a line like chalk?

Tags: iphone, ios, line, draw

I want to draw line, like chalk. And the line's edge is faint. Just like use chalk draw on blackboard.

How do I get this?
Now, I had drawed line using image, but it doesn't look like draw on blackboard, because the line is not faint. 
Please, give me some suggestions.

Here is my code:

```
    for (NSDictionary *dictStroke in self.arrayStrokes)
    {
        NSArray *arrayPointsInstroke = [dictStroke objectForKey:@"points"];
        //UIColor *color = [dictStroke objectForKey:@"color"];

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"]];

        float size = [[dictStroke objectForKey:@"size"] floatValue];
        [color setStroke];      // equivalent to both setFill and setStroke

        // draw the stroke, line by line, with rounded joints
        UIBezierPath* pathLines = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        CGPoint pointStart = CGPointFromString([arrayPointsInstroke objectAtIndex:0]);
        [pathLines moveToPoint:pointStart];
        for (int i = 0; i < (arrayPointsInstroke.count - 1); i++)
        {
            CGPoint pointNext = CGPointFromString([arrayPointsInstroke objectAtIndex:i+1]);
            [pathLines addLineToPoint:pointNext];
        }
        pathLines.lineWidth = size;
        pathLines.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
        pathLines.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
        [pathLines stroke];

        arraynum++;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use a pattern image with zebra lines. That would give you the effect like chalk writing.

```
brushPattern = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.jpg"]];

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [brushPattern setStroke];
    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0]; // myPath - points to be drawn    
}
```